# android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2) ERROR

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 100;

    private TextureView textureView;
    private Button captureButton;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private String cameraId;
    private Handler backgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread backgroundThread;
    private Size previewSize;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private String currentPhotoPath;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    private CameraManager cameraManager;
    private ImageView backgroundImageView;
    private Button toggleButton;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean isBackgroundThreadRunning = false;
    private ValueAnimator animator;
    private CameraCaptureSession session;
    private CameraCaptureSession previewCaptureSession;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // 상단바와 네비게이션바 숨기기
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        backgroundImageView = findViewById(R.id.background_image);

        // 저장된 테마 인덱스 가져오기
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int themeIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt("currentThemeIndex", 1);

        // 테마에 맞는 배경화면 설정
        String imageName = "b" + themeIndex;
        int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        if (drawableId != 0) {
            Drawable backgroundDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableId);
            backgroundImageView.setImageDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
        }

        toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.button_toggle);

        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggleTheme();
            }
        });

        // BluetoothPrinter 클래스 생성자 호출 시 권한 요청
        //mPrinter = new BluetoothPrinter(this);
        textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
        captureButton = findViewById(R.id.capture_button);

        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playButtonSound();
                setTimer(5);

            }
        });
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            // 권한이 모두 허용되었을 경우 실행할 코드 작성
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void toggleTheme() {
        int themeIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt("currentThemeIndex", 1);
        themeIndex = (themeIndex % 7) + 1;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("currentThemeIndex", themeIndex);
        editor.apply();
        setThemeBackground(themeIndex);
    }
    private void setThemeBackground(int theme) {
        int themeIndex = theme;
        // 테마에 맞는 배경화면 설정
        String imageName = "b" + themeIndex;
        int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        if (drawableId != 0) {
            ImageView backgroundImageView = findViewById(R.id.background_image);
            backgroundImageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
        }
    }
    private void setTimer(final int seconds) {
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView); // 타이머를 출력할 TextView
        final View flashView = findViewById(R.id.flash_view); // 플래시 뷰
        final GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) flashView.getBackground(); // 배경 drawable 가져오기

        final Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
        if (animator != null) {
            animator.cancel();
        }
        handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 1000; // milliseconds
        captureButton.setEnabled(false);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            int countdown = seconds;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (countdown > 0) {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(countdown)); // 남은 시간을 초 단위로 TextView에 출력
                    textView.startAnimation(shake);
                    countdown--;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                } else {
                    captureButton.setEnabled(true);
                    textView.setText(""); // 타이머 종료 시 0을 출력
                    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    // 찰칵 소리 재생
                    playShutterSound();

                    // 플래시 뷰 애니메이션 적용
                    animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.9f, 0.1f, 0.9f); // gradientRadius 값을 변경하는 애니메이션
                    animator.setDuration(20);
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            // UI 스레드에서 변경
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    gradientDrawable.setGradientRadius(value); // radientRadius 값 변경
                                    flashView.setBackground(gradientDrawable); // 배경 drawable 적용
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                            // UI 스레드에서 변경
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // 애니메이션 시작시 플래시 뷰 표시
                                    flashView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            // UI 스레드에서 변경
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // 애니메이션 종료시 플래시 뷰 숨김
                                    flashView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    takePicture();
                                }
                            });
                            // 사진 촬영

                        }
                    });
                    animator.start(); // 애니메이션 시작
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    private void playShutterSound() {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shutter_sound);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        mp.start();
    }
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        boolean allGranted = true;

        for (String permission : PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                allGranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 권한 확인
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            allGranted = false;
        }

        if (!allGranted) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // 권한이 허용된 경우 실행할 코드 작성
            } else {
                // 권한이 거부된 경우 처리할 코드 작성
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

            setupCamera();
            openCamera();
            textureView.setRotation(-90.0f); // 텍스쳐뷰를 90도 회전
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    private void playButtonSound() {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_sound2);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    private void setupCamera() {
        cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String id : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id);
                if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                    previewSize = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
                    cameraId = id;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void openCamera() {
        cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, cameraDeviceStateCallback, backgroundHandler);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback cameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            camera.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private void startPreview() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) {
            Log.e("tag", "Camera device is null. Not starting preview.");
            return;
        }
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        try {
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        previewCaptureSession =session;
                        CaptureRequest captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
                        session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, null, backgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, backgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if (cameraDevice != null) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            setupCamera();
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        if (!isBackgroundThreadRunning) {
            backgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
            backgroundThread.start();
            backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
            isBackgroundThreadRunning = true;
        }
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        if (isBackgroundThreadRunning) {
            backgroundThread.quitSafely();
            try {
                backgroundThread.join();
                backgroundThread = null;
                backgroundHandler = null;
                isBackgroundThreadRunning = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) {
            cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, cameraDeviceStateCallback, backgroundHandler);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            // previewCaptureSession을 사용하여 이미 열려있는 카메라 디바이스를 사용
            if (previewCaptureSession != null) {
                cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                Size[] jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

                int width = textureView.getWidth();
                int height = textureView.getHeight();

                ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
                reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageAvailableListener, backgroundHandler);

                CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
                // 세피아 필터 적용
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SEPIA);

                if (Arrays.asList(characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION)).contains(CameraMetadata.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON)) {
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CameraMetadata.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON);
                }
                if (Arrays.asList(characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODES)).contains(CameraMetadata.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON)) {
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON);
                }

                CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    }
                };

                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(reader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        try {
                            session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    }
                }, backgroundHandler);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener imageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image image = null;
            try {
                image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                buffer.get(bytes);
                saveImage(bytes);
                image.close();
                startPrintActivity();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (image != null) {
                    image.close();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void saveImage(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        File file = createImageFile();

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            outputStream.write(bytes);
            currentPhotoPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
    private void startPrintActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrintActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image_path", currentPhotoPath);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg");
        return image;
    }
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

This is the complete code from my MainActivity.java, and I'm encountering a 'CameraAccessException' with the following details:

```
Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
                                                                                         android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): cancelRequest:518: Camera device no longer alive
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1149)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:97)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1151)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:526)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:737)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:244)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
                                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
                                                                                         Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: cancelRequest:518: Camera device no longer alive (code 4)
                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
                                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUser.java:676)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1151) 
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:526) 
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:737) 
                                                                                            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:244) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
                                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I'm unsure where exactly this error is originating from and how to solve it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

'm not sure where the problem is occurring and I don't know how to go about resolving it